# Spring boot Security, Oauth2 replace access token with long-lived token from facebook

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud

I have been following [Dave Syer astounding tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2) to implement OAuth2 in microservices which provide RESTful APIs for mobile devices (Android and iOS). I have configured gateway security with the following code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class GatewayApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;
    private SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    private ScoreAuthorizationFilter scoreAuthorizationFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/test", "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/error**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and().addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(scoreAuthorizationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        ;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter facebookFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/login/facebook");
        OAuth2RestTemplate facebookTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(facebook(), oauth2ClientContext);
        facebookFilter.setRestTemplate(facebookTemplate);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(facebookResource().getUserInfoUri(), facebook().getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(facebookTemplate);
        facebookFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
        facebookFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
        return facebookFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook.client")
    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails facebook() {
        return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook.resource")
    public ResourceServerProperties facebookResource() {
        return new ResourceServerProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter> oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter>();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor getFeignClientInterceptor() {
        return new FeignClientInterceptor();
    }

}
```

It turns out that the user's session expires after a while. As I dug a little deeper, I found out that Facebook doesn't provide refresh tokens. Instead, we can exchange a short-lived token for a long-lived token ([Facebook long-lived token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/)). How can I override the standard OAuth2 flow implemented in Spring Security to send another request to Facebook for getting the long-lived token and then replacing the old access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by extending the `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` class like this:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

    private AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, ?> authenticationDetailsSource = new OAuth2AuthenticationDetailsSource();

    private ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails facebook;

    private String longLivedTokenUri;

    public CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        setAuthenticationDetailsSource(authenticationDetailsSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTokenServices(ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices) {
        this.tokenServices = tokenServices;
        super.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher) {
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
        super.setApplicationEventPublisher(eventPublisher);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken;
        try {
            accessToken = restTemplate.getAccessToken();
        } catch (OAuth2Exception e) {
            BadCredentialsException bad = new BadCredentialsException("Could not obtain access token", e);
            publish(new OAuth2AuthenticationFailureEvent(bad));
            throw bad;
        }
        String longLivedToken = getFromFacebook(); //Get long lived token from facebook here
        try {
            OAuth2Authentication result = tokenServices.loadAuthentication(longLivedToken);
            if (authenticationDetailsSource != null) {
                request.setAttribute(OAuth2AuthenticationDetails.ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE, longLivedToken);
                request.setAttribute(OAuth2AuthenticationDetails.ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE, accessToken.getTokenType());
                result.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
            }
            publish(new AuthenticationSuccessEvent(result));
            return result;
        } catch (InvalidTokenException e) {
            BadCredentialsException bad = new BadCredentialsException("Could not obtain user details from token", e);
            publish(new OAuth2AuthenticationFailureEvent(bad));
            throw bad;
        }

    }

    private void publish(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (eventPublisher != null) {
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.